# Swagger documentation does not update after deployment using Azure release pipeline

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, swagger, documentation

I am using Swashbuckle and swagger to document my .NET Core (3.1) API project.

The documentation is updated fine at the swagger endpoint, when I use the publish functionality in Visual Studio 2019 16.4.2.

However using the release pipeline in Azure does achieve the same.

Using swagger gen like this:

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "SqlViewService",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "Alter views..."
                });
            });
```

I initially started adding the endpoint in the startup.cs class like this:

```
app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(s =>
            {
                s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SqlViewService v1");
            });
```

And after searching a few articles and questions I have tried this:

```
app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(s =>
            {
                s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SqlViewService v1");
                s.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
```

And also this, adding current directory to the path:

```
app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(s =>
            {
                s.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SqlViewService v1");
            });
```

According to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

None of the tries have worked. Does anybody have a good suggestion or actual solution?

Comment: I've just checked for .net core 2.2 application. It shows the swagger definition https://appname.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ for service that was uploaded with Azure pipeline. Do you really have swagger working locally but not for Azure app service ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Like I said, the documentation is available at the endpoint .../swagger, both locally and on the host. But it does not update after making changes to models used for input to the API and then deploying using azure release pipeline. Maybe I was not clear about that.

Comment: looks strange. Swagger generates the `/swagger` page dynamically according to the  controllers methods definitions. So, probably, you have azure app service /swagger web page cached somhow. Do you have both visual representation `/swagger` and json file `swagger/v1/swagger.json` outdated on the Azure app service ? Had you tried to refresh the page (F5, Ctrl + F5) ?

Comment: Refreshing the page does not help. I am interested in the caching you mention. Could you elaborate beyond refreshing? However, I cant connect the dots, when things are working out of the box with the Visual Studio publish and not with the Azure Web App Deploy task for IIS.

Comment: I mean web browser cache by "cached". However page refresh should be enough to deal with it. Are you sure that Azure App Web deploy actually deploys the modified REST service to the azure web app ? Is there any error in the deploy log? Do you see the difference after the app was deployed? I'd like to suggest to add the test method\controller that outputs date, time and assembly version. Using this you can check that azure app was actually updated.

Comment: @oleksa, nothing but success on the deployment, no warnings, only info. Adding image of this to the question. I am sure the modfied service is deployed as I have a client requesting it and a required tag on the new property in the model. So the client was not able to request the service with the old payload. I could add additional info for debugging. But I am confident that the service is actually deployed and updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following with in the Startup.cs class in the Configure method:

```
 s.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
```

In this section:

```
 app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(s =>
        {
            s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SqlViewService v1");
            s.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
        });
```

To solve page not found which suddenly started appearing.
Which prevented me from seeing whether the changes I made in my release pipeline was working, once that was solved.

The path to the folder used for deployment was:

[image: Path to folder]

And as my folder path for files to deploy was wrong I was basically deploying into a folder within old application files, so the release was never "picked up" by IIS.